# How to Install TideSDK on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/) on Ubuntu 13.10, but the project website does not contain any installation instructions. I am looking for basic instructions on how to install the tool. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: By the way: they have their own section on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidesdk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mm... they doesn't have any instructions about how to install, so I had to <strike>play around</strike> figure out how to install it:

First, I'm downloading the TideSDK-1.3.1-beta for 64-bits. The following should work backwards and forward any version of Ubuntu if you use the same version of the software (Ubuntu installations methods are far more stables than 3rd party's).

```
wget http://cloud.github.com/downloads/TideSDK/TideSDK/TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-linux-x86-64.zip
```

Now unzip it. (I would recommend to start in a clean folder to prevent weird behaviors)

```
unzip TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-linux-x86-64.zip
```

we get 3 directories: modules, runtime and sdk (WHY!), create and move all the resulting directories to `~/.tidesdk` directory (seems that they don't want to mess up with sudo, *sighs*), or in a nutshell:

```
mkdir ~/.tidesdk && cd  ~/.tidesdk
wget http://cloud.github.com/downloads/TideSDK/TideSDK/TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-linux-x86-64.zip
unzip TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-linux-x86-64.zip
```

Supposedly, people used to TideSDK should know how to use it, but I don't. So, apparently for beginners, is easier to install the Developer App:

```
mkdir ~/TideSDK-Developer
cd ~/TideSDK-Developer
wget https://github.com/downloads/TideSDK/TideSDK/TideSDK-Developer-1.4.2-linux-x86-64.tgz
tar xf TideSDK-Developer-1.4.2-linux-x86-64.tgz
```

#### Now some notes:

Supposedly, you should be able to run it just typing `~/TideSDK-Developer/TideSDK Developer` in a terminal, but in my case, it "segfault"-ed (throw a `Segmentation Fault(coredumped)`). Finding the reasons I found that to build the Developer helper I [needed some dependencies](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/TideSDK-Build-Ubuntu-12.04) (some of them I had already installed or using another versions) which wasn't included in the Getting Started guide:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential ruby rubygems libzip-ruby1.9.1 scons libxml2-dev libgtk2.0-dev python2.7-dev ruby-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libnotify-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libxss-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev git-core libsoup2.4-1 libsoup2.4-dev libsoup-gnome2.4-dev libicu-dev libgnutls-dev libjpeg62-dev libenchant-dev libmcrypt4 libsqlite3-dev
```

If you are mysteriously unable to start the application, please install these dependencies. End of note.

#### Testing

You maybe want to checkout that everything is ok, so lets test a HelloWorld example:

```
wget https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK-HelloWorld/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
```

Now go to your application window, click import, look for the directory you decompress it, hit OK.

[image]

Once your app is imported, you will see a "Test & Package" tab.

[image]

Click it, then hit "Launch App",

[image]

you will be asked for confirmation to run the application, hit "Ok", now you should be seeing this window:

[image]

That's all.

Comment: Rant: this was needlessly complicated. Where is my good ol' `python install.py`?

Comment: You get an upvote for all the work ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Just one question, does TideSDK have to be installed for the developer app to work or can I just install the developer app?

Comment: I have no idea... as you can see by me comment above the whole thing took me about 1 hour to make it "work". I didn't fiddle around trying to install just the Developer app, but if I have to guess, install them both just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Saved me the hour figuring it out.

Comment: This project is defunct. The links referencing it are now broken. A final copy exists on github from 2012. https://github.com/amoschov/TideSDK